# How to increment elements in list by another character

Tags: list, haskell

I have string `"* * *     *"` and I want to get `"*2*2*10001*"` but my function can change only one side and I don't know how to increment `Char`.

I don't know how to make right conditions for this syntax, so sorry for my newbie questions.

`rowIncrements` shoud increase every single character by **' * '** possition. e.g. "0*0*" -> "1*2*"

The function receives two parameters.
@string which is a line/row
@list of integers which has loaded indexes of positions '*'

I would need all the numbers in the string around the '*' characters to be incremented by the number of occurrences next to them.

```
replaceNth :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceNth _ _ [] = []
replaceNth n newVal (x:xs)
  | n == 0 = newVal:xs
  | otherwise = x:replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs


rowIncrements :: String -> [Int] -> String
rowIncrements [] _ = []
rowIncrements x [] = x
rowIncrements row pos = changeInc pos where
  changeInc [] = []
  changeInc (x:xs)
    | x == 0 && (x+1) `notElem` pos = rowIncrements (replaceNth (x+1) '1' row) xs
    | (x+1) `notElem` pos = rowIncrements (replaceNth (x-1) '1' row) xs 
    | otherwise =  -- only for testing
```

Now I will get `"*1*1*00001*"` instead of `"*2*2*10001*"` this is everything new for me, so if you can, please improve me.

Comment: It is not clear what your function `rowIncrements` should do. Please try to explain which rules translates the string `"* * *     *"` to `"*2*2*10001*"`.

Comment: `rowIncrements` shoud  increase every single character by ' * ' possition. e.g. "00" -> "12"

Comment: It is still not clear how the rules are. Also what do you mean by _increase_. Also also add the explanation to the question text not as a comment.

Comment: Also you you word it like there is only the string as input to `rowIncrements` but it also takes an int list as input. Please add a proper explanation for the function together with some more inputs and their corresponding outputs.

Comment: @Ackdari better now?

Comment: _"I would need all the numbers in the string around the '*' characters to be incremented by the number of occurrences next to them."_ but why is it then that `"00" -> "12"`? Are you implementing somekind of minesweeper clone?

Comment: @Ackdari Yes something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conditionaly change characters to ints and increment by 1.

```
replaceNth :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceNth _ _ [] = []
replaceNth n newVal (x:xs)
  | n == 0 = newVal:xs
  | otherwise = x:replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs

replaceNths :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replaceNths _ _ [] = []
replaceNths [x] [y] str = replaceNth x y str
replaceNths (x:xs) (y:ys) str = replaceNths xs ys (replaceNth x y str) 

rowIncrements :: String -> [Int] -> String
rowIncrements [] _ = []
rowIncrements x [] = x
rowIncrements row pos = changeInc pos where
  changeInc [] = []
  changeInc (x:xs)
    |(x == 0) && ((x+1) `notElem` pos) = rowIncrements (replaceNth (x + 1) (intToDigit(digitToInt(row !! (x + 1)) + 1)) row) xs
    | (not(x == 0) && (x - 1) `notElem` pos ) && ((x + 1) `notElem` pos) = rowIncrements (replaceNths [x-1, x+1] [(intToDigit(digitToInt(row !! (x - 1)) + 1)), (intToDigit(digitToInt(row !! (x + 1)) + 1))] row) xs 
    | not(x == 0) && ((x + 1) `notElem` pos) = rowIncrements (replaceNth (x+1) (intToDigit(digitToInt(row !! (x + 1)) + 1)) row) xs 
    | not(x == 0) && ((x - 1) `notElem` pos) = rowIncrements (replaceNth (x-1) (intToDigit(digitToInt(row !! (x - 1)) + 1)) row) xs
    | otherwise = changeInc xs -- This shoud not be called
```